# ERROR: No such property: sonatypeRepo for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer

Tags: java, gradle

I cloned the Signal Protocol repo (https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-protocol-java) and facing an error with Gradle. I also downloaded Gradle and followed the procedure as instructed here (https://gradle.org/install/). After verifying the installation, here is the Gradle version on my system:

```
$ gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-02-08 19:00:10 UTC
Revision:     f02764e074c32ee8851a4e1877dd1fea8ffb7183

Kotlin DSL:   1.1.3
Kotlin:       1.3.20
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_201 (Oracle Corporation 25.201-b09)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

But, when I build the project that I am working on, I continuously receive this error:

**ERROR: No such property: sonatypeRepo for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer**

Please, any help would be highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue has already been raised on this Github project, see https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-protocol-java/issues/40  (and also message from the corresponding forum: https://community.signalusers.org/t/gradle-build-instructions-for-libsignal-protocol-java-master-missing-variables/1873)

The missing properties are credentials used by the `uploadArchives` tasks, I guess you won't need to call this task so you can just create the missing properties and provide dummy values.

One way is to create a `gradle.properties` file in your root project directory, with the following content :

```
sonatypeRepo=unused
whisperSonatypeUsername=unused
whisperSonatypePassword=unused
```